# Best way to search in the multivalued string

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server had experience in NoSQL database and I want to create a field of user_skills which will be multivalued(something like array in case of Mongodb) and perform search on the field which will also be an array most probably.

So the scenario I have is like

```
req.body.skills = ['javascript','php','angular']

Select first_name,last_name from users where user_skills IN (req.body.skills)
```

`user_skills` field will be like `['1','2','3','4']` having ID's of skills.

Input: searched string `['php','java']`

Output: List of all users having php and java in user_skill column.

1. What would be the best data type for user_skills field?

I can pass the ID's too in the search skill req.body.

Comment: I sense this question is really about how to execute your query from a programming language (PHP?  JavaScript?), and you want to know how to use a string array of skills.  If so, then please update your question with your code.

Comment: What would be the best data type? Normalize your model! Don't store multiple values in a single column. The this gets as easy as a JOIN with an IN condition.

Comment: Normalize, normalize, normalize. Create another table with a foreign key

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using react JS its not php,javascript was just an example.
Charlieface ,a_horse_with_no_name Can you please provide a example of the table and query which will perform the same operation. Thanks in Advance!